# Structuring MVC project with Java (backend) + Vue.js (front)

Tags: java, json, vue.js, tomcat, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a project that would be processing the images, labeling / modifying certain components of an image. My question is: I'm thinking of achieving it using Java (probably JSON as a NoSQL data structure) with Tomcat server. Vue.js would be sort of a frontend.
However, it is mandatory to maintain MVC model, and here is where I am confused. What will be model here? What is going to be a controller exactly?

I am thinking of having a controller in Java as well as model. But in that case, if I understood correctly, I won't have view there and instead my view will be in vue.js part. But doesn't it mean that vue.js "sub-project" won't have controllers / models (to maintain mvc structure) which is not possible? Or do we place them all in one place with contr/models in java and vue.js in view folder? But how do we launch them, do we launch them as separate projects? (tomcat + vue.js)
It is preferable to use Java with Tomcat but I find Vue.js appealing and easy to use (also, there are quite some tutorials regarding it). However, I'm confused about the structure of the project. Do I combine them later?
Thanks for any help. Please, don't be harsh, I'm a newbie.